# Connect raspberry pi with 4G

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a robot (use raspberry pi 3) outside my home (no internet connection there) and I'm with my laptop at home and I want to see the graphical environment (with all applications it has) of raspberry pi.
How can I do this?
I'm thinking to get 
[this module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FSGNYBJ) with a SIM card to put it to raspberry pi.

Answer (score 5):

First that module might not be the right thing to start with, it looks to present a raw tty header that you will have to wire to the right pins on the pi. You may do better with a USB 4G stick to start with and will probably get better speeds.

Secondly, you will then need to use pppd to start the connection. (This might not be required as most 4G/LTE USB devices present at USB Ethernet devices these days)

Third, unless you get a special M2M data plan you are very unlikely to get a public IP address you can use to connect to the pi. This will mean you will have to run some sort of VPN on the pi to connect back to server you can use to route traffic to the device, then setup VNC or X forwarding to run GUI based applications.

Depending on the circumstances it may be better to just install an external WiFi access point to give you WiFi access outside.

Comment: Can you send me any link ,because I have no idea about all these?